# Apple Script to create a new tab to run a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, macos, applescript, macos-sierra

I'm trying to write a function to creates a tab and run a command using Apple Script.

---

## I've tried

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    
    my makeTab("desktop", "ls")
    
end tell

on makeTab(name, command)
    
    do shell script command
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "i" using {shift down, command down}
        keystroke tab
        keystroke name
        key code 53
        
    end tell
end makeTab
```

---

## Result

I kept getting

> sh: eCmd: command no found

[image]

Any hints for me on how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a terminalogy conflict, `name` and `command` are reserved terms of AppleScript.

You can't use these terms as parameters of an handler.

---

Check the color of these variables.

- the color of the variables must be **green**.
- **Purple** : it's a property or a constant
- **Blue** : it's a command or a class

---

So, change the name of these variables.

If you want to run a command in the new tab, use the `do script` command, not `do shell script`, like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    my makeTab("desktop", "ls")
end tell

on makeTab(tName, tCommand)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "i" using {shift down, command down}
        keystroke tab
        keystroke tName
        key code 53
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script tCommand in front window -- run the command in the new tab
    end tell
end makeTab
```

Comment: I got this little error when I run your suggested script `Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.` Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to add a line in the script with the `delay 0.3` command after the `key code 53 ` command

Comment: Okay will do. Thanks.